# Aligning Div's under each other while centering

Tags: css, html, alignment

I succeeded in centering my divs on my webpage, but I can't figure out how to align seperate div's under each other?(when still centered). 
It's a blog, so when I add something, the div beneath the "blog"-div should move automatically. (margin is thus not a solution)

Greetings

```
.blog {
 background: transparent;
 height: 1200;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: solid -4px #a19a9a;
 width: 700px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -350px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -30px;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
```

}

same code for the other div.

The "container":

```
#content{   
width: 750px;
margin-top: 65px;
text-align: left;
height: 9000px;
overflow-x: hidden;     
}
```

For all the code: http://www.janwillemlibeer.be/verticaal

Comment: Hello, can you please provide some HTML of your site, and/or the CSS you have tried so far? Greetings.

Comment: Did you try adding {clear:both} to the divs and then adding them to the page? FYI: Alex is right, you'll need to post *some* code to help us help you :)

Comment: Yeah, this is a pretty ambiguous question. Some code would help, but if your problem is trying to get `<div>`'s to go under each other try using `display: block` and `clear: both`, like @nupul suggested.

Answer (score 3):

well there is tens of methods to do such thing.. but not all might work in your example.. Its much easier to find out which one if you provide some code.

I would use such solution, group up all of the blog divs in a container.

**part of index.html**
`<div class="container">

    <div class="blogdiv"><!-- content of blog here --></div>

    <div class="blogdiv"><!-- content of blog here --></div>

    <div class="blogdiv"><!-- content of blog here --></div>

    <div class="blogdiv"><!-- content of blog here --></div>

    <div class="blogdiv"><!-- content of blog here --></div>

</div>`

**styles.css**
`.container {

    width: 200px;

    margin:0 auto;

}`

.blogdiv {
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 20px;
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin: 3px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

go here for the example ---> http://jsfiddle.net/2WJm7/

but as I have said... there is a lot of methods to achieve this result but not all might work for you until you show us the code

EDIT:

ok so first of all You should not put some crazy height values... if you put min height: 20px; it will auto resize your div if the content is too big...
if you want to center the content just use margin:0 auto;
remove position: absolute; so it lets the second blog div to go under.
Overflow-x is pointless in this example as well.  here is code which i changed:

**css**

```
.blog {
 background: transparent;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 4px solid  #a19a9a;
 width: 700px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 30px;
 clear:both;
}

#content{   
width: 750px;
margin-top: 65px;
text-align: left;
min-height: 20px;    
}
```

**html**

`<div class="content">

    <div class="blog">asudhasbdjsabdaushdusab saudhsab dsuadh sauhd iusahd bsabd sadjsa ub d</div>

    <div class="blog">sadsad sasdas frw</div>

    <div class="blog">suadguiasgduiasb gasyudh shavduis auydb iuasbvd unqwhbv ub ihbiusbvduib bni busib ub iubyu buih bviun buyvb ou vuqiw</div>

    <div class="blog">yauhdiuasbduasndbasubdas</div>

    <div class="blog">test</div>

</div>`

edit:

**Your CSS fixed**

```
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, em, font, img, small, strong, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend {
    border: 0 none;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Dincond";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("fonts/dincond-bold-webfont.eot?") format("eot"), url("fonts/dincond-bold-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/dincond-bold-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("fonts/dincond-bold-webfont.svg#webfontabKpQmB0") format("svg");
}
@font-face {
}
#content {
    float: none;
    padding-top: 65px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
body {
    background: url("images/bkg.jpg") repeat fixed center center transparent;
    font-family: Georgia,"Lucida Sans","Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Grande",Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#blog p {
    color: black;
    font-family: Lucida Grande;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 130%;
    padding-left: 0;
}
#blog a {
    color: #1277A6;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#blog a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
h2 {
    color: #1277A6;
    font-family: Dincond;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
}
h3 {
    color: #990000;
    font-family: Dincond;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
#menu p {
    color: #4D4B4B;
    font-family: Dincond;
    font-size: 31px;
}
.blog, .contact {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-image: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    border-color: #E5E5E5 #DBDBDB #D2D2D2;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#begin {
    border-bottom: 2px dashed #A19A9A;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: fixed the css and explained a bit of what was wrong... hope it helps you man

Comment: I added the link already a few hours ago! It's in the main message, at the bottom. :)

Comment: sorry man (: didn't notice :P I fixed your css .. just copy and replace your old one ... I putted .contact together with .blog so they have the same parameters... removed height so the windows resize automatically depending on how big the content is... I removed all margins and position:absolute which was crashing your blog... instead of that I used margin: 0 auto; to center everything.... Hope it fix the problem ! :)